# Regex in Node.js not showing all matches

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

To prepare a request-url for an API-call I am using RegEx to replace values from a String with values from an object.

Example of a 'template-string':

```
'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/:ownerId/:collectionType/date/:date.json'
```

where :ownerId, :collectionType and :date will be replaced by the values from the following object:

```
{ collectionType: 'activities',
   date: '2016-10-12',
   ownerId: 'xxxxx',
   ownerType: 'user',
   subscriptionId: 'xxx' }
```

The regular expression I am using is:

```
/:([\w]+)/gi
```

This allows me to use the content of the group in every match to fetch the value from the object. (the match without the ':' in this case) I have the following function to return the request-url: (url is the 'template-string' and decoded is the object above)

```
function regexifyUrlTemplate(url, regex, decoded) {
  console.log('Regexify URL: ', url)
  console.log('Regexify Data: ', decoded)
  var m
  while (( m = regex.exec(url)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++
    }
    console.log('Matches: ', m)
    url = String(url).replace(m[0], decoded[m[1]])
    console.log('Replaced ' + m[0] + ' with ' + decoded[m[1]])
  }
  console.log('Regexify :', url)
  return url
}
```

The console shows me the following logs:

```
Regexify URL:  https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/:ownerId/:collectionType/date/:date.json
Regexify Data:  { collectionType: 'activities',
   date: '2016-10-12',
   ownerId: 'xxx',
   ownerType: 'user',
   subscriptionId: 'xxx' }

Matches:  [ ':ownerId',
  'ownerId',
  index: 31,
   input: '\'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/:ownerId/:collectionType/date/:date.json\'' ]
Replaced :ownerId with xxx
Matches:  [ ':date',
  'date',
  index: 59,
 input: '\'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/xxx/:collectionType/date/:date.json\'' ]
Replaced :date with 2016-10-12

Regexify : 'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/xxx/:collectionType/date/2016-10-12.json'
```

It successfully replaces :ownerId and :date but does not replace :collectionType. I verified the RegEx at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) and went through the regex with the updated strings from the logs.

Can anyone explain why :collectionType is not being matched? The only difference I can spot is the 'T' but with [\w] that should not matter. (also tried [a-zA-Z]).

Comment: forgot to mention, there are multiple url-templates for different API-calls. The RegEx should be fine, otherwise regex101 wouldn't return all groups.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Just do `url.replace(regex, function(_, k) { return decoded[k]; })`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was here `url = String(url).replace(m[0], decoded[m[1]])`

You modify `url` during the `exec()`, so matche's index change ...

```js
var url = 'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/:ownerId/:collectionType/date/:date.json';

var data = { collectionType: 'activities',
   date: '2016-10-12',
   ownerId: 'xxxxx',
   ownerType: 'user',
   subscriptionId: 'xxx' }

var reg = /\:([\w]+)/gi;

function regexifyUrlTemplate(url, regex, decoded) {
  console.log('Regexify URL: ', url)
  console.log('Regexify Data: ', decoded)
  
  var m, originUrl = url;
  while (( m = regex.exec(originUrl)) !== null) {
    //if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    //  regex.lastIndex++
    //}
    console.log('Matches: ', m)
    url = String(url).replace(m[0], decoded[m[1]])
    console.log('Replaced ' + m[0] + ' with ' + decoded[m[1]])
  }
  console.log('Regexify :', url)
  return url
}

regexifyUrlTemplate(url, reg, data)
```